# Running phantomjs from a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line, phantomjs

I'm interested in using [Phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/) and I'd like to run it from my Ruby on Rails application. However, this is a command line tool (i.e. I'd need to run something like `phantomjs rasterize.js http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html clock.png` in my terminal). How would I execute a command line tool from my app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use backticks in your ruby code e.g.:

```
output = `phantomjs rasterize.js http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html clock.png`
```

Comment: didn't realize it was that simple. If I install Phantomjs locally will it still work once I push my code to a server like Heroku's?

Comment: Probably not, because PhantomJS has to be installed on the server itself (I have neither used Heroku nor PhantomJS myself). I think that would be another question itself: Is there any way to run PhantomJS on Heroku.

Comment: For future reference - the followup question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445438/running-phantomjs-on-heroku

Comment: I needed the same thing, but this did not work. Putting a "&" at the end of the command like this did work on the other hand: system('phantomjs rasterize.js http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html clock.png&')