# Running Phantomjs on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, phantomjs

Is there a way to run [phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/), a command-line tool, on Heroku?

Comment: Looks like an awesome tool! I wrote my own website capture program using C++ around a year ago. I wish I had known about this. Let me look into it for you.

Comment: Looks like no for a number of reasons. http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/platform-constraints Perhaps you could just run on a VPS? That would be a way to get around the constraints.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with VPS. Any good sources?

Comment: Go to Linode and look at the community page. They have tons of resources to help you. Also take a look at ServerFault for general server questions. I usually set my server up with Debian 6, MySQL and Phusion Passenger. If you google how to set up a rails server on debian it should point you to a few good guides.

Comment: what's the reason you choose Debian over Ubuntu?

Comment: I like it more, you can use Ubuntu if you want. There virtually the same thing.

Comment: Have a look at [https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs](https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs)

Answer (score 5):

check out this buildpack:

https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs

I also am able to run the x86_64 build of PhamtomJS, just stuck in my app's `vendor` directory:

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Answer (score 3):

In Version 1.5 we got rid of the Xvfb and Xlib dependencies.
Now this should be pretty simple.

I'd suggest:

- checkout the source
- build a binary with the given script (check the options to build the version without xvfb)
- be happy :)

Ariya, the main author, also did a good job at incorporating Qt in our codebase directly, so we have a tailored, stripped down Qt that does just what PhantomJS needs and no more :)

Comment: It also works just by using the build from the downloads page. I tried PhantomJS 1.5.0 Linux x86_64 (Dynamic build) on a cedar stack app and it worked. I just put the bin and lib folders in my app.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Phantom, but it looks like a binary, in which case there's a Heroku buildpack which might help you out here:

https://github.com/ryandotsmith/null-buildpack