# Deploy phantomJS to node.js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, phantomjs, casperjs

I realize ["Running PhantomJS on Heroku"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445438/running-phantomjs-on-heroku) is a related but slightly different question as I am trying to use a node app.

I'm having trouble deploying a casperJS (based on phantomJS) script for a node app.  I've tried deploying to Heroku by placing the PhantomJS 64-bit binary in my app's `/bin` directory, but I get the following error when I try to run PhantomJS:

```
phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

From what I've read this can be solved by installing the QtWebKit library, but Heroku does not have this installed.  Is there another hosting provider I could use that will work or a way to install this package on Heroku?

Relevant code:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  var sys = require('sys')
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;
  var child;

  //works but gives error while loading shared library libqtwebkit.so.4
  child = exec("phantomjs --version | tr -d '\n'", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
    sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr + '\n');
    response.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.send('_testcb(stdout:' + stdout + '\nstderr:' + stderr + ')', 200);
    if(error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
  });
});
```

I've signed up for beta-testing on Nodester but their documentation is still pretty limited at this point.

EDIT:  I was able to get it working by simply copying the lib folder of PhantomJS to the root directory of my node app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the lib folder of phantomjs to the root directory of your node app
You could also try putting a sym link in bin or sbin
The key is that is has to run from terminal using the same account that node runs on.
Also, node-phantom is a good npm library to utilize phantomjs, once you get it working.