# How to determine if a web page has insecure elements programmatically?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver for test automation and need a way to determine if my test page is triggering the insecure content warning in the browser or if it is loading any resources in http instead of https.

Is there a way to do this in watir-webdriver? Or is there another tool I could use to do this?

**For example**, if you go to https://github.com and look at the network traffic you will see a bunch of .js files and images that are loaded via https. I need a script that would be able to determine if any of those resources were loaded using http instead of https. The major browsers will have some kind of warning when this happens on a secure site, but they don't always create a popup.

[image]

Comment: Check all links for `"http"`?

Comment: @Casper my test page contains javascript widgets. The resources those widgets load are the main focus of the test

Comment: If you come up with a good solution to this, please tell me so I can start a business.

Comment: Please provide example HTML or even better link to the page. Do you want to check if browser notifies the user about insecure content, or if the content is there, or both?

Comment: @Željko I updated the question with some more detail. I want to either check if the browser realizes there is insecure content or if any of the content is loaded via http.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to capture the requests sent by watir-webdriver with `pcap` ([ruby-pcap](https://github.com/ahobson/ruby-pcap), [tutorial](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2005/10/linux-20051002/)). Your code would be something like this:

```
require 'pcaplet'

# start capturing packets
httpdump = Pcaplet.new('-s 1500')

#
# do web requests here
#

insecure_reqs = []
httpdump.add_filter(
  # you could also filter by just tcp and then check pkt.dst_port in the loop
  Pcap::Filter.new('tcp and dst port 80', httpdump.capture)
)

httpdump.each_packet do |pkt|
  insecure_reqs << pkt.dst.to_s
end
```

(Disclaimer: This is untested and cobbled together from ruby-pcap's [example](https://github.com/ahobson/ruby-pcap/blob/master/examples/httpdump.rb).)

The downside is you'll need to ensure nothing else on your machine is making requests while your test is running, so running this in an isolated server or VM would be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

What I've been developing works for 99% of cases.  You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and execute it from within your Ruby code using [backtics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443945/running-phantomjs-from-a-ruby-on-rails-application), or use [this GEM](https://github.com/westoque/phantomjs.rb), capture the output, then filter through it.  They even have a sample called netlog.js which can be used out of the box.

The output is HAR, or HTTP archive, which is what you are looking at in your screen grab, but that's been prettied up.

The 1% of the time it doesn't work is if a Flash file calls an element that is http.  I've seen this in ads.  If you have no Flash ads on your site, it shouldn't be an issue.  Mine do and now I'm working on that 1% ;)